# Cause of file open error with _lopen because of unexpected file lock

Tags: windows, iis, iis-6, file-locking

I'm maintaining a desktop application that accesses data on servers.  Multiple users can access the same files.  We have a library that opens the files for retrieval using _lopen (C library function).  We always open read only with SHARE_DENY_NONE.
To improve performance, we keep the file open until the user exits the application.  That is when the file is closed.
However, if there is no activity for over 20 minutes, we will lose the connection to the server.  In that case we start the connection and open the file again.  Supposedly there is a file close operation called when the connection is lost, but there is no proof that the file close is called.

Unfortunately, once or twice a day users get an error message that they are unable to open a file.  We think this is because the file is locked, because we can't open it in explorer either.  The only way to clear the error is to call IISRESET so that all the file handles for retrieval are cleared.  However, today we got the error message which is a generic file open error, and we were able to open the file in explorer and also clear the problem by recycling the app pool.

Because some users get the file open error as soon as they start the application before they have done anything, we think that this problem must be caused by some other user (or process) locking the file.  We are unable to replicate the error.

I have reviewed the source code to see how the file is opened.  I have reviewed Process Explorer and the file is always accessed by our software.  I have reviewed process monitor and seen that the file is opened permitting read/write operations by other users, and that the file is closed when the application closes.  We never get the error on our development servers, but only on the production servers.  The error doesn't depend on large numbers of users, because we can't replicate it using a test program that opens the file 1000 times with 1000 different users.  Also, we have seen the error with only 9 users.

I hope someone can suggest additional tests to try or additional reasons this problem might occur.

Comment: Does it happen always for those 9 users? Does it matter if they switch to a different client pc? I assume everything is Windows OS? Can you mention the specific versions? Which version of iis is used?

Comment: Everything is in Windows Server 2003 iis 6.0.  Problem is not limited to those 9 users.  Many different users have had this problem.  The problem is occurring on the server, not on the client pc.  The clients are using remote surveys, so the retrieval is started with a web service call which then calls programs on the servers. We are now checking to see if the problem is limited to only one server (we have 3 which are assigned depending on load).

Comment: _lopen is deprecated in Visual Studio.  Could this be the problem?